# Accessing class variables using class or object?

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, variables

What is the best practice / difference between accessing a class variable using the class or using a object created by the class?

for example I have the following class and creating an object:

```
class MyClass():
    class_variable = 10

    def __init__(self):
        self.object_variable = 5

object = MyClass()
```

I can access the class_variable in two ways:

```
object.class_variable
myClass.class_variable
```

I cannot see any difference as these two possibilities will always return the same value.

Comment: Long story. Please read about python namespaces on a book. I recommend [Mark Lutz's](https://learning-python.com/)

Comment: They are equivalent; generally you'd access through an instance if you have an instance, otherwise the class.   Care needs to be taken when mutating the value though, especially if it is a mutable object like a list or dict.

Comment: Machine Markus, I am crediting you with a good question!  This is a keen observation on your part which forced me to investigate and test sample code leading me to concur with snakecharmerb, that they ARE equivalent.  I would add that in the interest of consistency, and not reinventing the wheel, that you should WANT to take advantage of referring to the class variable through the instance if possible (since you can't refer to instance variable through the class due to scope), and consistency is greater than inconsistency, so given the choice choose consistency.